# Refactoring for adding Key Parameter

Tags: flutter, android-studio

The Dart Analyzer always tells me, that I should add the Key parameter to the widget constructor. To solve the analyzer message *Use key in widget constructors*, I have to change the constructor from:

```
const SomeWidget({required String this.someParam});
```

to:

```
const SomeWidget({Key? key, required String this.someParam}) : super(key: key);
```

In Android Studio there are a lot of refactoring (Project quick fix, Alt+Enter/Option+Enter), but nothing for adding the Key Parameter. Is there a reason why this refactoring is missing or is there another trick to add this automatically?

Comment: *"but nothing for adding the Key Parameter"* - `Alt+Enter` gives you "Add 'key' to constructors" action

Comment: Thank you! I found out, that I only get the *add 'key' to constructors* refactoring, when the constructor isn't a const constructor. When it is a const constructorI only get *Convert to block body*, what makes no sense, because const constructors can't have a body.

Answer (score 0):

this is because of the `flutter_lints` package, in my opinion it's not that important and you can just remove the package and the `analysis_options.yaml` file and you don't need to add the `key` parameter anymore.